# Select Nth element in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<dict>
    <key>LogType</key>
    <string>Pass</string>
    <key>Message</key>
    <string>Test Case</string>
    <key>Timestamp</key>
    <date>2015-05-18T11:30:12Z</date>
    <key>Type</key>
    <integer>4</integer>
</dict>
```

Am using for each to convert this into a HTML Table element, now I need to print the outcome (Pass/Fail) and the message (Test case). XML(Plist) generated does not have unique keys, so how can I access the second `string` ?

```
<xsl:value-of select="string"/>
```

This will give me the first string.

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//string)[2]"/>
```

I came across this, but it always prints the 2nd string in the Plist. I need to pick the second string while its a loop in for each.

How can I get this ?

Comment: Ddi you try `<xsl:value-of select="string[2]"/>`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Damn ! Time to take a coffee break I guess.